# How to find and replace using sed text containing a star *

Tags: text-processing, sed

I would like to find and replace text within many `.procmailrc` files, and using `grep` and `sed`.

I would like to remove the following line (including the new line break at the beginning) from the `.procmailrc` files:

```
* !^FROM_MAILER
```

The full contents of the file I want changed from:

```
:0
* !^FROM_MAILER
! myemail@email.com
```

to:

```
:0
! myemail@email.com
```

The command I am running is:

```
grep -lir '\n* !^FROM_MAILER' .procmailrc | xargs sed -i 's/\n* !^FROM_MAILER//g'
```

But it is not replacing the `*`. In leaves the line in with just the `*` on it. If I escape the `*` as follows, that also does not work:

```
grep -lir '\n\* !^FROM_MAILER' .procmailrc | xargs sed -i 's/\n\* !^FROM_MAILER//g'
```

So I trying to find out how to do the find and replace to remove the entire line with the `*` in it.

Comment: Part of the answer is that `sed` operates on lines of text, where a line of text is a sequence of characters *between* one newline and another (or before the first newline); therefore, you generally don't include `\n` in `sed` commands.  (There are some exceptions.)  Your commands with `\*` might have come close to working if you had left out the `\n`.  (Similarly, don't think in terms of deleting `\n` characters; think in terms of deleting *lines*.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `sed` alone:

```
sed -i '/^* !^FROM_MAILER$/d' file
```

To remove the whole line containing the exact string `* !^FROM_MAILER`, with nothing before and after that string. The `d` command deletes the line.

---

**Edit**: If you want to do the replace in all files recusively, use the following:

```
find /path -type f -exec sed -i '/^* !^FROM_MAILER$/d' {} +
```

Comment: How would I do it for all files in a folder with sed alone? The grep command is to search all files and replace in all files. Thanks.

Comment: @LaurenceCope just riun the command on all files. Those that don't contain the pattern will be left untouched. `sed` is _very_ fast, it won't make much difference in the time it takes.

Comment: @LaurenceCope See my edit

Comment: Don't you need a backslash before the asterix? or is it not necessary when its the first character? (I suppose I should just go and look that up :-)